# How to differentiate HTTP method in html file?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have two one REST end point which will hit the html file with GET and POST.
Example: 
         http://192.28.120.21:8098/RestEndpiont/rest.html -- GET request
         http://192.28.120.21:8098/RestEndpiont/rest.html -- POST request with post parameters in the body.
When ever end point is calling, it hits the "rest.html" file, then how can i differentiate in the html file for HTTP method(GET/POST).If the request is GET, I have to return rest.html file otherwise it should be reditrecting to other html file.

Could any body have any Idea to achieve the above requirement.

Comment: thank you @zerkms. So is there any alternative to achieve my requirement?

Comment: You cannot tell if the page was requested with POST or GET from the document javascript.

Comment: What server-side technology are you running? There are ways to do this by processing the request from Java, PHP, etc., but not in a normal html file.

Comment: I don't think you will even be able to retrieve any POST values from JavaScript.